# run() method of interface tool throws NullPointerException in JDK 9

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, java-9, java-compiler-api

//Following is Hello.java file.

```
public class Hello{
    public static void main(String... s){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to compile the above class using Java Compiler API as following:

```
import javax.tools.*;
public class CallingJavaCompiler{
    public static void main(String... s){
        JavaCompiler comp = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int i = comp.run(System.in,System.out,System.err,"Hello.java");
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

While executing CallingJavaCompiler class (**using JDK 9**), it throws java.lang.NullPointerException at run method. I'm unable to understand why it's throwing the exception when there's a string type argument?

Here is the stacktrace which I'm getting while executing it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CallingJavaCompiler.main(CallingJavaCompiler.java:5)
```

On the other hand excecuting same program i.e, CallingJavaCompiler in **JDK 8**, it is executing **without any runtime exception**.

Please help me in understanding why is it throwing Null Pointer Exception (NPE) when I'm executing it using JDK 9?

**Note:** I'm compiling above piece of code using javac 9.0.4 and executing it with java version 9.0.4. While compiling and executing with these version, I'm getting NPE, but not with JDK 8.

Comment: What package structure do you have?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I'm unable to understand what are you asking. Can you elaborate? I'm new here

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to the exception that you are getting and make sure the above piece of code is exactly the same with which you're able to reproduce the NPE.

Comment: @nullpointer I have edited the question and add the stacktrace that i'm getting. Also above piece of code is exactly same with which I'm learning

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I have see but it's still not working. I'm trying to learn about module-info.java. Any help would be good contribution towards me

Comment: Tell me the exact path of the JDK 9.0.1 home directory

Comment: I have updated the JDK to 9.0.4. Here is exact path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin

Comment: OK, now execute:  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java" CallingJavaCompiler using command line in D:\java\compiler\  directory

Comment: But 'C:\program' is not recognized as an internal or external command. This is what I'm getting

Comment: Because you forgot the quotations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working. It would be useful for all if you edit your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace Hello.java with the full path to Hello.java file (ex C:\Test\Hello.java). Anyway, I didn't get NullPointerException even when the path to Hello.java is wrong.

**UPDATE**

I was able to reproduce your java.lang.NullPointerException error. It appears when running the program with JRE instead of JDK. This way, no compiler is found since the compiler is only available in JDK version.

**UPDATE2**

So you are using the command line to run the program.

When executing with `%jdk_home%/bin/java` you are using JDK and when executing with `%jdk_home%/jre/bin/java` you are using JRE.

I see you compile with JDK 9.0.1 and run with JRE 9.0.4. To make it work execute something like:

`%JDK 9.0.1 home%/bin/java CallingJavaCompiler`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have replaced it, but it is still throwing Null Pointer Exception when I'm executing it with JDK 9. Please explain why?

Comment: Why the downgrade?

Comment: @AbhishekMishraIt's tough to answer the question with incomplete details. The stacktrace shall help understand the cause of the exception. Though the fully qualified path is good to have in your args.

Comment: It would be useful to run `java --list-modules` and see if "jdk.compiler" (different to "java.compiler") is in the list. As explained in the answer, the JRE does not have the jdk.compiler module and ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler returns null. This is not behavior in JDK/JRE 9 of course, same thing in JDK 8 and older releases.

Comment: @AlanBateman Right, but I didn't want to link my answer to 9th version, since it applies to 8th as well.

Comment: @nullpointer I have edited the question and add stacktrace. My program is running with JRE 9, not JDK 9. I don't know why? How can I make it correct?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I have add the stacktrace in question

Comment: @AlanBateman jdk.compiler is not in the list. java.compiler. Is it wrong? If yes, how can I make it correct?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [`ToolProvider#getSystemJavaCompiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler--):

> This implementation returns the compiler provided by the jdk.compiler module if that module is available, and null otherwise.

I suspect that your `jdk.compiler` module is unavailable for some reason (you might be running the program with JRE 9 and not JDK 9), hence why you'd be receiving a `NullPointerException`.  To be sure, I recommend adding it to your `module-info.java`, even though it doesn't seem to be required.

```
module Hello {
    requires jdk.compiler;
}
```

---

Anyway, I was able to solve your problem by supplying the full path to `Hello.java`, as shown below.  This works on Windows; if you use any other OS, then you should use `File.separator` or `System.getProperty("file.separator")` rather than `\\`.

```
JavaCompiler comp = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

int i = comp.run(System.in, System.out, System.err,"src\\main\\java\\Hello.java");

System.out.println(i);
```

Output:

> 0

**Note**: The path begins from the root directory of my project (the parent of the source folder, `src`).  Remember to include any packages by appending to the directory where necessary.

Comment: The question is "Using JDK 9 do you get this error?". Because I didn't

Comment: @EugenCovaci The question (taken straight from the OP's post) is: "Please help me in understanding why is it throwing exception when I'm executing it using JDK 9?"  Not technically a question, but it's explained at the top of my answer.

Comment: The addition of the `jdk.compiler` module seems not required, would have been good to know the exact stacktrace I believe to avoid those assumptions to fix the code.

Comment: @JacobG. You are right about your suspicion. My program is running with JRE 9 not JDK 9. My program is compiling with JDK 9 but running with JRE 9. I don't why? How can I make it correct? What is module-info.java and how should I use? I don't about this. I'm student and want to learn it. Please help. I'm googling and trying to solve this on my own.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS Code and running the program using command prompt.

Comment: current directory is D:\java\compiler\ In this directory there are two files CallingJavaCompiler.java and Hello.java. I'm compiling the CallingJavaCompiler.java in command prompt using command **javac CallingJavaCompiler.java** and executing it with **java CallingJavaCompiler**. And getting Null pointer exception at run() method as mentioned in stacktrace

Comment: I've never used VS Code, but I'm sure there's a way to run your program with JDK 9 rather than JRE 9.  You could even uninstall JRE 9 entirely.